# Basic search service for autocompletion

Tags: php, search, solr, amazon-cloudsearch, searchify

I have a movies database and would like provide a search with autocompletion on my site. Could somebody recommend any free cloud services or a PHP script for this. I'm using a free hosting at the moment and cannot install solr. I would prefere not to pay as well. Found amazon's CloudSearch, searchify and some others but you always need to pay for it after a trial. My application is a prototype now so it would be ok if the provider would have a fair plan to which I can switch later and I query-number limited but not time limited trial

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at Azure Search? It includes a free service for up to 10,000 documents and it has search, suggestions/auto-completion, faceted search, etc.

More details here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/search/